# REST and C process integration

Tags: c, rest, embedded-linux

I have a need to provide restful api support to a linux deamon process that will maintain and manipulate a in-memory table (simple C structure of arrays). This deamon will act as a configuration entity and will relay the table contents to another process on its bootup or during configuration request.
Now in this context i would be happy to obtain the following information:

1. Would it be good to have an integrated web server or have an independent web server and talk to this daemon. Please note this server would not be required to handle huge loads.
2. Please suggest some good web servers with good REST support.
3. If an independent web server then what is the best mechanism for web server to deamon communication.

Please note this would be deployed on a small embedded board running debian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, a possible solution is based on developing a CGI that is executed by any webserver (apache, lighttpd, ...) . This program connects to the main daemon with an IPC mechanism such as sockets, fifos or message queues and after interacting with the daemons returns the desired output to the REST client.

The CGI program can be written in any language, but if you want to write it in C, check this [project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/psia/): it's a CGI program written in C that takes commands for an IP camera. The connection with a main daemon is not implemented, since it was outside the scope of the project. I like it because it has an embedded XML parser and does not require any external library